# isort GitHub Action fails due to a docker daemon error

Tags: python, docker, github-actions, isort

I would like to create a GitHub Action running the isort module and committing the changes with the following `yml` script:

```yaml
name: Sort imports with isort

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master, development ]
  push:
    branches: [ master, development ]

jobs:
  format:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Run isort
      uses: olance/isort-action@v1.0.0
      with:
        args: ./src

    - name: Commit changes
      run: |
        git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
        git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
        git add -A && git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD || git commit -m 'isort'
    - name: Push changes
      uses: ad-m/github-push-action@v0.5.0
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The action runs, however, during the `Run olance/isort-action@v1.0.0` step it returns the following error:

```sh
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown.
```

Is this a problem with my `yml` configuration file? Basically, I copied the configuration from the [Marketplace](https://github.com/olance/isort-action).

Comment: I face the same issue when running this tool. However, I'd ask the github developer about it and not on stackoverflow, as it is specific to his implementation.